# HierarchicalDataTemplate doesn't display items without children

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659253/hierarchicaldatatemplate-for-treeview) I wanted to know, how to set up the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for a `TreeView`. This just works fine. My problem now is the following:

The class `ClassPupils` looks like:

```
public class ClassPupils
{

   public ClassPupils(Class @class)
   {
      this.Class = @class;
      this.Pupils = new List<Pupil>();
   }

   public Class Class { get; set; }
   public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have an `ObservableCollection<ClassPupils>` where the TreeView is bound to.

If a `ClassPupil` has no Pupils in the Pupils-Collection, the item is not displayed. I don't understand why? I need to also display ClassPupils with no Pupils in the Pupils-Collection.

Comment: post your datatemplate and tree xaml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is incorrect. Our data models in code often do *not* exactly follow that of our database structure, especially when the data is hierarchical... remember, our tables are normalised, whereas there is no benefit from doing this in code. So your database table may have the foreign key Id of a Class in a child table, but in a business model, this is usually implemented as a parent class that has a collection of children. So in your case, your *parent* class should look more like this:

```
public class SchoolClass
{
    public SchoolClass(List<Pupil> pupils)
    {
        this.Pupils = pupils;
    }

    public List<Pupil> Pupils { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

There is no need to define a 'weak entity' or 'joining table' in code. Whereas your problem before was that your parent `SchoolClass` class did *not* have a collection of `Pupil`s, now it does, so try your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` again.

Comment: That means that the Pupil-Class doesn't know it's Class. But the Class has a Collection of Pupils?

Comment: No, that means that in code, there is no such thing as a `PupilClass`... that is *only* in your database model.